# How to over take brand keywords in Google SERP?

Tags: seo, google-search, ranking

Nowadays Google gives importance to branded websites rather than displaying small players. Example, You can not over take Amazon / Snapdeal / Flipkart when it comes to Ecommerce space in online.

What are the methods or things can be done to over take or display my website in better position than Google ?

IMO, Creating a "quality content" as per google's guideline really does not work. You will create a quality content and wait for many years for Google to recognize it, This will not work out.

Comment: Get bigger than them.

Comment: @Steve, It is true. But for a small company getting bigger than them is not possible. I am just trying to explore other possible way.

Comment: There are quite a few answers that address branding on this site. It can be a bit of a large topic. You can always use the branding tag to see if there are any ideas that may be useful to you. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/branding

Comment: @steve, your comment is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

For some keywords, you don't really have a chance unless you have a huge budget and e-commerce brand.

Google prefers e-commerce brands for product oriented keywords with buying intent. For example `nike shoes online` or `buy nike shoes online`. Google knows if someone is searching for such term then they want to buy a product, so Google boosts e-commerce websites in SERPs.

Google learns from trends and displays information based on what people are really doing when they search for a specific term.

On top of this, these e-commerce brands/websites spend tons of money to be on top of such keywords. So it's better to avoid them.

Although there are many keywords where Amazon/ebay is in top 5-10 results because of specific information displayed on that page + their authority. You can take over these keywords but will need some work.

You will not only need quality articles in that specific field/niche but also few quality backlinks from authority websites in same/broader niche. You will need to show that you have authority in that field.

I follow a rule of thumb, if a keywords have 3+ e-commerce websites then it's useless for me.